# error in printing contents of array in C

Tags: c, arrays

After i assign values to my array, and try to print its content using the for loop. The first few values of output are not the values assigned to the array.

input:-r 45 23 32 43 53 ed // these are the contents assigned to array

output:- ▒▒ 45 23 32 43 53 ed // i get that weird thing as my first value.

As the size of the array grows the more values that show up like that(▒▒).
How can i fix this so the output is as same as the input?

code used to print is as follows:

```
 char **values = malloc(argc*sizeof(char));
```

`for(c=1;c<=argc;c++){
         printf("test value:%s\n",values[c]); // values contains the value
    }`

Comment: it is better you give the rest of your code, especially the definition of values array.

Comment: @rggod Edit your question and add the necessary information. `argcsizeof` is nonsense.

Comment: @rggod That's just gibberish. *Edit your question don't post code in comments.*

Comment: @rggod  What is "values"? Why is used argc? Is it so difficult to show a minimum compiled program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in `C` are zero-based.

Run your index from `0` to < `argc`:

`for(c = 0; c < argc; ++c){`

Don't use `<= argc - 1` as this will give you trouble if `argc` is an `unsigned` type.

Also, don't read back the values in an array until you've assigned values to them. The behaviour on doing that is undefined in C.

Comment: See my last point. You've probably messed up the initialisation of values.